# How to list the most recent questions without being disturbed by the even newer questions?

Tags: support, pagination

One way I look at questions to answer is to use `newest`. When I have looked through the 50 most recent questions (their titles, not literally every question), I used to press Next and then I would get the next page. However, that page doesn't show me the 50 posts older than the ones I just looked at, but the ones which are at that moment the 51-100 newest ones. This makes it next to useless for me to browse questions that way, because there have probably arrived about 50 new questions in the meantime, and so I see the very same ones again.

This is of course not hard to understand, and is not an error. But is there a convenient way to read new posts in a linear fashion without duplications?

The alternatives I am using now are two: 1) stay on the first page and refresh it; 2) once a day, look at yesterday's posts.

Comment: You can open several pages beforehand using middle click or ctrl click, if you do this fast enough before new question was asked you will get the list of questions.